# Kafka Producer and Consumer Issues

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have two issues with Apache Kafka.

### **Issue 1**

1. Push 100,000 messages to Kafka
2. Shutdown zookeeper and kafka services with Ctrl-C before the consumer 
   consumes all the 100,000 messages (This was simulated by having a 
   `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the consume method).

**Discovery**

The consumer continued to write the messages on the console after the zookeeper and kafka services have been shutdown.

**Expectation**

The consumer should stop consuming messages and restart from the index of the last message + 1 after the zookeeper and kafka have been brought up.

**Question**

How do I make the consumer continue from the index + 1 of the last consumed message.

### **Issue 2**

1. Push 100,000 messages to Kafka
2. Shutdown zookeeper and kafka services with Ctrl-C before the consumer 
   consumes all the 100,000 messages (This was simulated by having a 
   `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the consume method).
3. Kills the spring boot application consuming the messages
4. Bring up zookeeper and kafka services.
5. Bring up the spring boot application responsible for consuming messages.

**Discovery**

The consumer consumes all the messages from beginning ignoring the last consumed message.

**Expectation**

The consumer should start consuming from index + 1 of the last consumed message before the spring boot application was brought down.

**Question**

How do I make the consumer continue from the index + 1 of the last consumed message.

### Code Snippets

**KafkaConsumerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs()
    {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "basic-group");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory()
    {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
            kafkaListenerContainerFactory()
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(100);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

**KafkaProducerConfig**

```
@Configuration
    public class KafkaProducerConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory()
        {
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs()
        {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate()
        {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        }
    }
```

**KafkaProducer**

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducer
{

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String message, final String topicName)
    {

        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);

        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result)
            {
                System.out.println("Sent message=[" + message
                        + "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata().offset() + "]");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Unable to send message=["
                        + message + "] due to : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**KafkaConsumer**

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer
{

    @KafkaListener(id = "basic", topics = "test-1", clientIdPrefix = "test-prefix-id", autoStartup = "true", concurrency = "3")
    public void multipleTransactionNotification(@Payload final String message)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**TestApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

   @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx, KafkaProducer producer, NIPKafkaConsumer consumer) {
        return args -> {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++)
            {
                producer.sendMessage("New Message-" + i, "test-1");
            }

        };
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue 1

Spring Kafka does a `KafkaConsumer.poll()` to fetch records and then calls your listener for each record.

So if the batch contains 100 records, it will take 100 seconds to proceed the whole batch with your actual KafkaListener.

## Issue 2

Consumer commits offsets to know where to resume from.

Default behavior is to automatically commit offset every 5 seconds. My guess is you kill your consumer before it commits its offset, that's why it restarts from the beginning.

See `enable.auto.commit` and `auto.commit.interval.ms` Kafka consumer configuration.

You can also manually commit your offsets.

See also `auto.offset.reset` to define what your consumer should do when it has no initial offset.

Comment: Spring for Apache Kafka prefers `enable.auto.commit=false`; the listener container will commit the offsets after each `poll()` or as each record is processed if the `AckMode` property is set to `RECORD`.